# How do I make the (active) color of my nav element fit the container?

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

In the nav bar I've created, I've noticed that the a:hover color attribute doesn't stretch to fill the container vertically.

I have tried to increase the vertical padding, which does work, however it doesn't look quite as clean, so I was hoping there was a better way to go about it.

```css
/*Navigation Bar*/

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #383838;
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav_bar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px 16px;
}

.nav_bar a.active {
  background-color: #33A2FF;
  color: white;
}

.nav_bar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav_bar">
    <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Stadium</a>
    <i class="fas fa-football-ball"></i>
    <a href="#">RSVP</a>
    <a href="#">History</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Basically, I'm just trying to stretch the color attribute to fit the box vertically.

Comment: remove `vertical-align: middle` from `.nav_bar a` and add `height: 100%; display: inline-block;` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `vertical-align: middle` and add `display: inline-flex;` to the a elements.

```css
/*Navigation Bar*/

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #383838;
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav_bar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  display: inline-flex; /* To align the elements horizontally */
  /* vertical-align: middle;  To remove the top spacing. */ 
}

.nav_bar a.active {
  background-color: #33A2FF;
  color: white;
  
}

.nav_bar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav_bar">
    <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Stadium</a>
    <i class="fas fa-football-ball"></i>
    <a href="#">RSVP</a>
    <a href="#">History</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```